# Can a card copying a double-sided planeswalker transform?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

If I have a [Dack's Duplicate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDack%27s%5d%2b%5bDuplicate%5d)  copying [Jace, Vryn's Prodigy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%5d%2b%5bVryn%27s%5d%2b%5bProdigy%5d), can it transform into [Jace, Telepath Unbound](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Telepath%20Unbound%5d)?

I imagine it would not — it would be similar to the rules for tokens right, it doesn't have the face to flip to, and in this case I would assume duplicate would just be exiled forever if it tried right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct about the outcome, but it is a different set of rules that deals with what happens here.

In the case of a Jace *token*, it can’t transform because tokens cannot exist outside of the battlefield, and can’t ever come back to the battlefield after leaving. With a non-token copy, we have this rule:

> 711.8a If a player is instructed to put a card that isn’t a double-faced card onto the battlefield transformed, that card stays in its current zone.

So the Duplicate will remain in exile.

Comment: What if the copied card is in fact a flip card? For example, we are getting Metamorphic Alteration in M19. What if I enchant my delver of secrets, copying Nicol Bolas, The Ravanger. Then I pay the cost on Bolas(Previously a delver) to flip into Bolas Planeswalker? Not sure if this is a different question or not - so I'll comment for now.

Comment: @Christopher That sounds like a separate (and good) question to me.

Comment: I feel like you would end up putting Insectile Aberration into play, but please do ask a new question because I'm not sure!